# Running multiple NodeJS servers in single command

Tags: node.js, npm, microservices

I have a parent folder and it includes multiple folders

each child folder is a NodeJS project

example

```
/ParentFolder/ChildFolder1
/ParentFolder/ChildFolder2
/ParentFolder/ChildFolder3
/ParentFolder/ChildFolder4
```

to run the project , I enter to each child folder and hit npm start , multiple times

I want a more professional way to run all the projects within a single command

I created a new file start.js , if I can put a NodeJS script inside it to handle this task

Answer (score 0):

I added a start.js file in ParentFolder with this content

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("cd ./ChildFolder1 && npm start");
exec("cd ./ChildFolder2 && npm start");
exec("cd ./ChildFolder3 && npm start");
exec("cd ./ChildFolder4 && npm start");
```

and used node start.js to start all the services